# Go to the stairs ask your mother come down

Tags: word-usage, grammar

We are about to go out.

My wife went to the washroom.

My son shouted his mother at downstairs.  So I told him:

> She can't hear you. Go to the **stairs** ask your mother come down.

Would it clarify the place of the location if just simply use "stairs"?

Comment: What location; the stairs? What's the intended meaning of your sentence?

Comment: Side note: You need a conjunction or some connector follow "go to the stairs". Or break it into two sentences. Also, it should be "to come down". Like "Go to the stairs AND ask your mother TO come down."

Comment: Are you asking whether the original phrasing, "go to the stairs", is sufficient, versus adding something else (like "go to the bottom of the stairs")? Or are you asking something else? It's not quite clear what you're expecting the answers to provide.

Comment: Another side note: "shouted his mother at downstairs" should probably be "shouted *at* his mother downstairs" (assuming that the mother is downstairs and the son is upstairs).

Comment: @KyleStrand - Given the "ask your mother to come down" part, I'd assume it's the other way around -- the mother is upstairs and the son is downstairs. With that assumption, it'd be "he shouted at his mother *from* downstairs."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stairs have a top and a bottom, so you can always say which you want:

> Go **up (to the top of) the stairs** and ask your mother to come down.
>
> Go **to the bottom of the stairs** and ask your mother to come down.

You don't have to specify, but then you leave the listener to guess from context. An alternate solution is to modify the *direction* of the action, which implies the location of the speaker:

> My son **shouted up** the stairs, "Mom, Dad wants to you to come down!"  (your son is at the *bottom* of the stairs)
>
> My wife **shouted down** the stairs, "I'll be there in a minute!"  (your wife is at the *top* of the stairs)

This only works with certain verbs, though.  "Shout", "yell", "call" and other loud vocalizations all work.  For some reason "whisper up/down" is also idiomatic, but not "speak", "ask" and other *normal* vocalizations.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to specify "go up the stairs" or "to the bottom" if you just mean "go to the nearest point of the stairs".  The original phrasing sounds perfectly natural to me.

Comment: @stangdon  I was trying to address OP's question.  He seems to be asking whether just saying "stairs" defines to *what part* of the stairs he wants his son to go.  I agree you can just say "stairs" even though it's ambiguous, because most of the time it's obvious to the listener.

Answer (score 18):

If you want him to speak at the bottom of the staircase, you can say

> Go to the stairs and ask your mother to come down.

If you want him to speak at the top of the staircase, you can say

> Go up the stairs and ask your mother to come down.

Comment: What if they wanted their son to climb an unspecified number of stairs (i.e., get on/climb the staircase a bit) and then to call his mother? *Call your mother from the staircase*?

Comment: It's worth noting that "go to the stairs" is not intrinsically the bottom. For example, if mother was in the basement or on a lower level, "Go to the stairs and ask your mother to come up" would imply that the son was at the top of the stairs when he shouted. "Go to the stairs" just means being at the stairs, without any up/down/middle connotation. Normally it will be assumed to be the nearest point, i.e. the bottom for stairs going up and the top for stairs going down.

Comment: @R.M.: Indeed. In a *multi* storey building, any point that accesses the stairwell could be the intended destination for *go to the stairs*. But in the contrived context of being on the middle level, *and* not knowing if the boy's mother is above you or below you, I guess you'd have to say *...and ask your mother to come **here**!* Sounds a bit "peremptory" though.

Comment: @R.M. I would say – if it's not explicitly stated – that the default interpretation of "where on the stairs" would be _the level the son is (currently) on_.

Answer (score 10):

You can also say:

> Don't shout. **Go upstairs** and ask her.

We can **go upstairs** and **go downstairs**.

*Upstairs* and *downstairs* refer to locations.  Go upstairs = go to *the floor above*.  Go downstairs = go to *the floor below*.

> Where is mom?
>   -- She is upstairs.

That is, she is on the floor above.

We don't say "*at* downstairs|upstairs".

Comment: This is presumably because the words "upstairs" and "downstairs" were _originally_ contractions of "up stairs" and "down stairs", and have maintained the grammatical context, even if the usage of both has diverged.

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to with "this", @wizzwizz4.

Comment: This is the last sentence.